# C++: Program stuck when reading file. Why?

Tags: c++, file, io

I'm trying to compile a C++ software with visual studio.

To run the program I use this command line:

```
ABC 0.85  x.txt < x.txt
```

The software look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
//main variables
float min_sup = atof(argv[1]);          //minimum support
string filename = argv[2];              //input file name

cout << "Hello" << argv << " " << endl;

if(argc < 2)
{
    cout << "[Error] Usage: <min> <input file> < <input file>" << endl;
    cout << "E.g: ./ABC.exe 0.85 input.txt < input.txt" << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;
}

//checking min_sup value
if(min_sup <= 0 || min_sup >= 1)
{
    cout << "[Error] Minimum  must be between 0 and 1 exclusively." << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 1;
}

int in_buf;
while(cin >> in_buf)
{

    .....
```

When I run the software, it get stuck at:

```
 while(cin >>  in_buf)
```

Do you know what is the problem?  Is it a problem with how the file is read?

I'm running the code on Windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: Contents of x.txt would be helpful.

Comment: x.txt is a large text file.  Each line is a list of integers . For example, one line could be :  "12 14 15 19 20"  .    I know that the program get stuck at the first line of the while because I used the debugger and the debugger get stuck there.   When I run the program from the command line, it also get stuck.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem is because of the "<" redirection operator

Comment: Are you running from a command line or the IDE? Have you tried without the redirect, typing in numbers?

Comment: Please provide a **complete**, **minimal** program that demonstrates the problem. A *complete* program is one which we can compile and run. A *minimal* program is the shortest program that demonstrates the error, devoid of everything unrelated to your question. Your example is neither complete, nor minimal. See http://sscce.org/.

Comment: When you ran it under the debugger, how did you launch the program? When you ran it under the debugger, how did you specify the input file redirection (the "<" part)?

Answer (score 1):

```
ABC 0.85  x.txt < x.txt
                 ^
```

You have an extra space.  You're passing the program three parameters. You want two parameters and a stream redirection.

```
ABC 0.85  x.txt <x.txt
```

You can display `argc` to verify this.

Why does the program need the filename of the "x.txt" parameter?  I can't think of any reason you'd need it.
Also, you shouldn't read the arguments until *after* you verify the count.

Comment: In the code given, he only looks at the first two. But, definitely a problem.

Comment: I count 3 parameters. The `<` is a piping or redirection symbol on Windows (command line) and Linux.  Also, my understanding is that the OS skips "extra" spaces, including the ones after the `<`.

Comment: It's possible that the OS skips the extra spaces, but I'm not sure, and it seems like if it did not, it would cause exactly the error described.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews It's the shell that handles redirection and cmdline->argv parsing, not the OS. As a rule, shells trim unquoted whitespace during parse, so a whitespace between `< << >> >` and the filename is unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem with the file.  I found the problem.

Comment: In visual studio, it works.  But in Eclipse CDT it does not work.  It must be some configuration problem or some bug with Eclipse. I'm using Eclipse CDT on Windows 7 64 bits.